# EXCEL: return 1 value from table based on 2 criteria being met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of shipping prices per number of units and by country. I'd like to have the total shipping cost appear on my order form once the number of bottles and country have been filled in elsewhere on the order form. Any ideas for what formula would do this?

```
Here's a small part of my table:
           1           2           3          4             5         6
France   €12.60      €14.40      €17.40      €19.44      €21.36      €23.40 
Belgium  €20.40      €26.40      €31.20      €36.60      €42.00      €46.80 
Germany  €20.40      €26.40      €31.20      €36.60      €42.00      €46.80 

So for the client shipping to Germany that selects 5 units, how do I get €42.00 to appear in the shipping cost cell?

Thank you
```

Answer (score 1):

INDEX with two MATCH's.

```
=INDEX(A1:G4,MATCH("Germany",$A$1:$A$4,0),MATCH(5,$A$1:$G$1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Substitute the text "Germany" and "5" for references to the cells where these values are entered in your order form and put the formula where you want your shipping value show up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach...

[image: DGET]

Suppose your data is in range `A1:G4` including headers,

Put your look up criteria in range `A6:B7`, and use the following formula to return the desired cost:

```
=DGET(A1:G4,""&B7&"",A6:A7)
```